# Lie algebra cohomology with values in injective module

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, lie-algebra-cohomology

I am looking for a proof of the following result: Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra and $I$ an injective $\mathfrak{g}$-module. Then $\mathrm{H}^q(\mathfrak{g},I)=0$ $\forall q>0$. More precisely, I am looking for a proof in a textbook so that I can cite it.
The result shows up in Weibel's book (Exercise 2.5.1), but only as an exercise (no proof).

Comment: Usually one defines $H^q(\mathfrak{g},M)$ as $\operatorname{Ext}^q_{U(\mathfrak{g})}(k,M) $, so the vanishing when $M$ is injective is obvious. To see that this is equivalent with the definition in terms of the Chevalley-Eilenberg complex, see Cartan-Eilenberg, chapter 13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define Lie algebra cohomology via injective resolutions, then your claim is trivially true, because you can take the injective resolution which is I in degree 0 and 0 in higher degrees.

To see that your preferred definition agrees with that via injective resolutions, you have to check two things:

1. any two injective resolutions are chain homotopy equivalent (this is a variant of the fundamental lemma of homological algebra and should have the same proof) and thus yield the same cohomology groups
2. your preferred definition uses an injective resolution

Comment: I use the definition via the Chevalley-Eilenberg complex, $\mathrm{C}^q(\mathfrak{g},I)=\text{Hom}_k(\wedge^q\mathfrak{g},I)$. Is there a way to get the result directly also with this definition?

Comment: It should be possible to write down the 0-homotopy directly. But this will be the same chain homotopy equivalence that one constructs in the proof of the fundamental lemma.